# How to add onClick trigger to an IconButton inside the TableCell

Tags: javascript, node.js, material-ui

I'm a newbie with MaterialUI therefore apologies if the question is too simple to solve.
I'm pulling some data, showing on a table, with an additional column that has a button attached:

```
<TableCell>
    {<IconButton> <ClearIcon /> </IconButton>}
</TableCell>
```

I want to add an `onClick` trigger to the `IconButton`. However, because the `IconButton` is nested inside the `TableCell` the trigger is not reachable. Simply because `TableCell` is overlapping the button.

When I add `onClick` to `TableCell` it works, however it is not a best practice. Thus, when the user clicks around the button it still triggers the `onClick`.

Any suggestion on how to overcome this issue? I also share the overlap view of TableCell in real time.

[image: Table Cell HTML over IconButton]

Comment: Have you tried increasing the z-index of IconButton? as long as it's higher than your TableCell you should be able to do this;

Comment: @IlanP that's a great idea! I will try and add here if it works!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add an onClick on the IconButton and then create a function to trigger it, I give you a code example you can try.

```js
<TableCell>
    <IconButton onClick={() => deleteData()}>
       <ClearIcon />
    </IconButton>
</TableCell>
```

Comment: I also tried this way at first hand however it doesn't work unfortunately. When the user clicks, it takes it as user clicked on TableCell, not IconButton and event is never triggered.

Comment: I provided this code for you because this code for me is worked.